# shared entity framework context

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I know creating a static data context for entity framework is really really bad idea but I kind of have a problem to solve.

So the project I am working on has lots of different services and data adaptors for data operations. Sometimes in a web api method, we are using multiple services and multiple data adapters, and in every data adapter, it's creating a new connection and closing, disposing which does not make any sense to me.

I thought of sending the connection as a parameter, but I guess it wouldn't look beatiful again.

I was wondering about DI with Microsoft Unity for entity framework but my project manager doesn't want me use that library.

Have you ever faced with a situation like this? How do you handle sharing a connection for multiple services or data adapters. Is it okay not to share, am I being too picky?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Comment: yes, sorry to not to mention that

Comment: Are they specifically against Unity or are other DI frameworks an option? Ninject, AutoFac, StructureMap, etc? I guess if they are against all DI that's not a very good position to take. :/

Answer (score 2):

> it's creating a new connection and closing, disposing which does not make any sense to me.

You don't know that.  The .Net Framework uses built-in [Connection Pools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx) to reduce all the overhead you appear to be talking about.

[SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.Net) (still used by EF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: yeah you are right. the product is on the development stage at the moment, i guess pooling is a nice feature but not sure if our current approach will be okay if we just depend on that feature.

Comment: How is pooling going to create problems?